# Magento 2 - Display Custom Product Attributes in Product Details Tab

Tags: magento2

I have created several custom product attributes and I need them to display on the Product Details tab if data has been entered in the Magento Admin. There are three in total and on a lot of occasions all three will have data but there will be around 20% of products where one or two of the have data.

I have created the attributes easily enough but I am struggling to get them to display on the frontend. I have pasted the code for the layout file and the phtml file for the attributes.

The result I am getting is a blank product screen with no info at all. Definitely an error somewhere but after hours of looking I am missing it.

Below is the custom catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">

          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description." template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
              <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
              <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
              <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
              <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>

          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="deliveryinfo.tab" as="deliveryinfo" template="product/view/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Delivery</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>

        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sidebar_delivery" after="-">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sidebar_delivery</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>

          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sidebar_instructions" after="-">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sidebar_instructions</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block> 

          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sidebar_brochures" after="-">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sidebar_brochures</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>

          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="sidebar_blog" after="-">
            <arguments>
              <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">sidebar_blog</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceContainer> 
    </body>
</page>
```

Below is product_attributes.phtml called in the Layout file

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div>
<?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
<div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php

$dimensions = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('dimensions')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$features_benefits = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('features_benefits')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$flooring_specification = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('flooring_specification')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

if (!empty($dimensions) || !empty($features_benefits) || !empty($flooring_specification) {
    ?>
        <?php 
        if (!empty($dimensions)) {
            ?>
            <h2>Dimensions</h2>
            <?php echo $dimensions; ?>
            <?php
        }
        if (!empty($features_benefits)) {
            ?>
            <h2>Features & Benefits</h2>
            <?php echo $features_benefits; ?>
            <?php
        }
        if (!empty($flooring_specification)) {
            ?>
            <h2>Specification</h2>
            <?php echo $flooring_specification; ?>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

It is probably something laughably simple I have done wrong but I can't for the life of me find it.

The site is on Community Edition 2.2.5 and the server is running PHP 7.1

Any suggestions appreciated.

Kev

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue in the end. I missed out a closing bracket.

This line:

```
if (!empty($dimensions) || !empty($features_benefits) || !empty($flooring_specification) {
```

Should have been:

```
if (!empty($dimensions) || !empty($features_benefits) || !empty($flooring_specification)) {
```

I knew it would have been something simple. Works perfectly now.